# Is Mona Ambegoakar inspired by or potraying any real life political figure?

Tags: character, mission-over-mars

*M.O.M. - Mission Over Mars* shows a lot of politics behind the funding and taking credit for scientific achievements. Two of the prominent political figures were Manmohan Singh and Narendra Modi which were played by actors who look too similar to be ignored for their resemblance to their real-life counterparts.

But I don't remember any Sunita Vyas who was portrayed by Mona Ambegoakar. Is she supposed to represent some real-life figure too?

Comment: Are there more political figures you can recognize?

Comment: @AJ only the metioned ones